# Isomorphism of functors Hom(P , _ ) and Hom(P' , _ )

Tags: category-theory, modules, representation-theory

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional algebra over a closed field and $P,P'$ two projective $A$-modules, If $Hom(P,V)$ $\simeq$ $Hom(P',V)$ for every $A$-module V (unnatural isomorphism of vector spaces) does this imply an isomorphism of the functors $Hom(P, \_ )$ and $H(P', \_ )$ in general ? If not I wish that I can see a counterexample.

Comment: What sort of isomorphism are you considering between $Hom(P,V)$ and $Hom(P',V)$? Sets, abelian groups, $A$-modules (if $A$ is commutative)?

Comment: @ArnaudD. Isomorphism of abelian groups

Comment: Do you have an example in practice where you can construct such isomorphisms, but not in a natural way?

Comment: If $A=\mathbb{C}$, $P=\mathbb{C}$ and $P'=\mathbb{C}^2$, then for every $A$-module $V$, $\operatorname{Hom}_A(P,V)\cong\operatorname{Hom}_A(P',V)$ *as abelian groups*, but $\operatorname{Hom}_A(P,-)\not\cong\operatorname{Hom}_A(P',-)$ as functors from $A$-modules to abelian groups. Are you sure you only want an isomorphism of abelian groups?

Comment: @ThibautBenjamin I'm reading the book Quiver Representations and Quiver Varieties for Alexander Kirillov jr. In the proof of Theorem 1.18, we have P and P' are two projective modules, he showed that Hom(P,S(i)) $\simeq$ Hom(P',S(i)) for every i $\in$ I (\{S(i)\} is a family of simple modules) using the fact that the spaces have the same dimension and then using projectivity of P and P' we get the isomorphism for any module V.

Comment: @JeremyRickard Thank you!! I have an example where isomorphism of Hom(P,V) and Hom(P',V) for every V imply an isomorphism of A-module P and P', In the book I mentioned in the last comment, and I can't understand why this is true. I'm not sure if the isomorphism is only of abelian group it may be isomorphism of left A-module but I'm sure that A is not commutative. What would be the case if it is isomorphism of modules ?

Comment: As you imply, if $A$ is not commutative, then $\text{Hom}_A(P,V)$ is not an $A$-module, so it doesn't make sense to ask for an isomorphism of $A$-modules. It sounds as though you might be assuming that your algebra is finite dimensional over a field, and you want Hom(P,V) and Hom(P',V) to be isomorphic as vector spaces over that field?

Comment: @JeremyRickard Exactly this is the case.

Comment: I suggest you edit the question to include that clarification. At the moment it doesn't specify that $A$ is an algebra over a field, or that it is finite dimensional, and doesn't say what sort of isomorphism you mean.

Comment: @JeremyRickard Done!! Thank you!!

Comment: @JeremyRickard I apologise for the inconvenience. I couldn't see why $Hom(P,V) \simeq Hom(P',V)$ for every $A$-module $V$ in the example you gave above, I would be grateful if you show it to me.

Comment: $\text{Hom}_\mathbb{C}(\mathbb{C},V)\cong V$ and $\text{Hom}_\mathbb{C}(\mathbb{C}\oplus\mathbb{C},V)\cong V\oplus V$. If $V$ is a nonzero $\mathbb{C}$-module, then it is an infinite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, so $V$ and $V\oplus V$ are isomorphic as rational vector spaces, or as abelian groups (but not as complex vector spaces).

Answer (score 1):

It is true that if $A$ is a finite dimensional algebra over a field $k$ and  $P$ and $P'$ are projective $A$-module, such that $\operatorname{Hom}_A(P,V)\cong\operatorname{Hom}_A(P',V)$ as $k$-vector spaces for all $A$-modules $V$, then $P\cong P'$ as $A$-modules.

The best way to prove it probably depends on how much you know about basic representation theory of finite dimensional algebras, but one thing that most introductions will prove early on is that there are finitely many simple modules $S_1,\dots,S_n$ and finitely many indecomposable projective modules $P_1,\dots,P_n$, up to isomorphism, which can be numbered so that $P_i$ is the projective cover of $S_i$ and $S_i$ is the unique simple quotient of $P_i$.

[I'll now assume, for simplicity, that $k$ is algebraically closed and that $P$ and $P'$ are finite dimensional, although neither assumption is really necessary.]

Then
$$\operatorname{Hom}_A(P_i,S_i)\cong\begin{cases}
k\text{ if $i=j$}\\
0\text{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

Every projective module is a direct sum of indecomposable projectives, so $P\cong P_1^{r_1}\oplus\dots\oplus P_n^{r_n}$ for some non-negative integers $r_1,\dots,r_n$, and then
$$\dim_k\operatorname{Hom}_A(P,S_j)=r_j$$
for each $j$. So the dimensions of the vector spaces $\operatorname{Hom}_A(P,S_j)$ determine the isomorphism type of $P$.

However, the book by Kirillov mentioned in chat, which is exclusively about representations of quivers, does not seem to have covered these facts about indecomposable projective modules before Theorem 1.18, and so I'm not sure what argument he had in mind.